# Which is better approach to get Zend_View

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

I am working on a Zend Framework based app, and in controller plugins, I can get Zend_View object with the following methods, someone please tell me which approach is better and why?

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
```

or

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
if (null === $viewRenderer->view)
    $viewRenderer->initView();

$view = $viewRenderer->view;
```

Comment: i will appreciate if you can share when layout approach is better and when viewrendrer should be used. Right now I am writing a controller-plugin and I need access to view object, so which approach better suits.

Comment: thous are two different things. viewRenderer is responsible for determining target view script and auto-rendering after execution of action. Zend_Layout is used general to layout scripts.

If you are using MVC you should be able to access view from controller using `$this->view`.

Comment: yes, I can access the view in controller, but I need to access view in a controller plugin and plugin object don't have direct access to the view. so need to know whci approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to pull it from the viewRenderer because then you're sure you'll always get it. You may not be using Layout in some contexts and then you won't get the view through the layout.

So, to be on the save side, pull it from the viewRenderer, it's more direct anyways and therefore faster too.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Zend_Layout::getView()` method looks like the following:

```
public function getView()
{
    if (null === $this->_view) {
        require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php';
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        if (null === $viewRenderer->view) {
            $viewRenderer->initView();
        }
        $this->setView($viewRenderer->view);
    }
    return $this->_view;
}
```

... i would prefer to use it ;)

Comment: What happens, when layout is not used?

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Controller_Action_Helper` defines `getActionController()` with which you can acquire the public view. Perhaps plugins have the same method. While I'm not fond of accessing it through a public property, I believe it's preferable to go through the helper's controller itself than the layout.

```
$view = $this->getActionController()->view;
```

Comment: thanks David, but I am not talking about Zend_Controller_Action_helper_Abstract, I am talking about Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract, and there we have only access to the response(Zend_Controller_Response_Http) and request(Zend_Controller_Request_Http) objects

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have the code in front of me to double-check. I suppose controller plugins are not designed to be used from the controllers themselves?

Answer (score 0):

both are two different things if you are pulling the view from layout than the return view instance basically will help you access view variables inside your layout.phtml , on the other hand taking view from viewRender action helper will help  you access view variables in your action.phtml (view for specific controller action) .

Comment: hmm, so you are saying that if I assign a variable to view from layout, the variable will be accessible only in the layout.phtml, while the variable assigned to view from viewRenderer is available in the action.phtml only. I think variable are available in both scripts, but not sure. checking...